# IIS hosted application stops when visiting web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis

I have an IIS Application Pool `Spark.Release` configured with a site pointing to a directory on a local C:\ drive.  The pool starts automatically but when visiting http://localhost/ the app pool changes to "Stopped" status.

In Event Viewer `Windows Logs > Application` I see this:

> There was an error during processing of the managed application
>   service auto-start for configuration path:
>   'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Spark.Release/'. The error message returned
>   is: ''.  The worker process will be marked unhealthy and be shutdown. 
>   The data field contains the error code.

In `Windows Logs > System` there are 5 occurences of:

> A process serving application pool 'Spark.Release' reported a failure
>   during application preloading or service loading. The process id was
>   '2344'.  Please ensure that all application preload or service
>   settings in the application pool are configured properly.  The data
>   field contains the error number.

Before this:

> Application pool 'Spark.Release' is being automatically disabled due
>   to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application
>   pool.

OS is Windows Server 2016 Datacentre edition.

Where can I begin troubleshooting this?  I'm not seeing any logs in my log directory either, literally zero.  It's running under the ApplicationPoolIdentity identity.

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com . Someone needs to access your server as well as the web app so as to know what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A required IIS module was not installed 'URL Rewrite' which was being used by the code.  There was no indication in any logs that this was the issue.